# Remove Any Non-Digit And Check if Formatted as Valid Number

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex pattern that allows a string but removes anything that is not a digit, a `.`, or a leading `-`.

I am looking for the simplest way of removing any non "number" variables from a string. This solution doesn't have to be regex.

This means that it should turn

```
1.203.00 -> 1.20300
-1.203.00 -> -1.20300
-1.-1 -> -1.1
.1 -> .1
3.h3 -> 3.3
4h.34 -> 4.34
44 -> 44
4h -> 4
```

The rule would be that the first period is a decimal point, and every following one should be removed. There should only be one minus sign in the string and it should be at the front.

I was thinking there should be a regex for it, but I just can't wrap my head around it. Most regex solutions I have figured out allow the second decimal point to remain in place.

Comment: Regular expressions don't transform anything; they "match" things (i.e. they accept regular languages). I'm pretty sure that the language of "substring that if removed will leave behind a valid number" is not regular, so you can't do this "with a regular expression".

Comment: @OrangeDog a regular expression using string.replace(<regex>,'') in javascript is what is currently happening, but like I said, I'm open to other ideas.

Comment: This could be done in O(n) time by checking each character and keeping track of - and . signs and throwing out any non digit character.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Yeah, I was really hoping someone would tell me there is a magical solution for this that would do it slightly faster and cleaner. The strings won't be long, so n won't be that big, but there will probably be a lot of them. Though I wonder if I'm just overkilling it. I asked because I had already spent too much time on trying to figure out a regular expression for this. Maybe I just need people to tell me "don't be silly, do it this way".

Comment: If you know all the cases that can occur, it might be easier [to match those](https://regex101.com/r/qE0vO9/2).

Comment: Use like this: [`str = str.replace(/[a-z]+|(?!^)-|(\.\d*)\./gi, "$1");`](https://jsfiddle.net/r410o7vu/)

Comment: @bobblebubble Has the correct answer.

Comment: @bobblebubble misses 1.2.3.4 -> 1.23.4 or ...1 -> ..1

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no solution with a single str.replace(...) as js regex doesn't support lookbehind (which would be needed to match dots preceded by other dots).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-regex solution, implementing a trivial single-pass parser.
Uses ES5 Array features because I like them, but will work just as well with a for-loop.

```js
function generousParse(input) {
  var sign = false, point = false;
  return input.split('').filter(function(char) {
    if (char.match(/[0-9]/)) {
      return sign = true;
    }
    else if (!sign && char === '-') {
      return sign = true;
    }
    else if (!point && char === '.') {
      return point = sign = true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }).join('');
}

var inputs = ['1.203.00', '-1.203.00', '-1.-1', '.1', '3.h3', '4h.34', '4.34', '4h.-34', '44', '4h', '.-1', '1..1'];
console.log(inputs.map(generousParse));
```

Yes, it's longer than multiple regex replaces, but it's much easier to understand and see that it's correct.

Comment: This is really easy to understand and process. Definitely much easier to understand than the regex solutions.

Comment: @Simon and currently more correct than your accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this replace approach:

- In the first `replace` we are removing all non-digit and non-DOT characters. Only exception is first hyphen that we negative using a lookahead.
- In the second `replace` with a callback we are removing all the DOT after first DOT.

**Code & Demo:**

```js
var nums = ['..1', '1..1', '1.203.00', '-1.203.00', '-1.-1', '.1', '3.h3',
  '4h.34', '4.34', '44', '4h'
]

document.writeln("<pre>")

for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
  document.writeln(nums[i] + " => " + nums[i].replace(/(?!^-)[^\d.]+/g, "").
  replace(/^(-?\d*\.\d*)([\d.]+)$/,
    function($0, $1, $2) {
      return $1 + $2.replace(/[.]+/g, '');
    }))

document.writeln("</pre>")
```

Comment: It fails running this string "4h.-34" it comes out "4.-34". However, running it on the result fixes the issue and it comes out 4.34.

Comment: Actually I had `g` missing in first `replace`. Now it should work for `4h.-34` as well.

Comment: @anubhava this if perfect. thank you. Also, thanks for showing me how to use the captured values. I'd missed that.

Comment: Fails on consecutive periods, e.g. `1..1`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it is fixed now with a simple change from `+` to `*`

Comment: The answer by @OrangeDog is much more readable and easier to verify that it's correct, when I deselected it the answer wasn't working 100%, which you've since fixed. OrangeDog's solution doesn't use regex - but I did say in the question that that wasn't a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I can do it with a regex search-and-replace. `num` is the string passed in.

```
num.replace(/[^\d\-\.]/g, '').replace(/(.)-/g, '$1').replace(/\.(\d*\.)*/, function(s) {
  return '.' + s.replace(/\./g, '');
});
```

Comment: You should make this a Stack Snippet to make it easier to test, but I haven't found anything wrong with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

OK weak attempt but seems fine..

```js
var r = /^-?\.?\d+\.?|(?=[a-z]).*|\d+/g,
  str = "1.203.00\n-1.203.00\n-1.-1\n.1\n3.h3\n4h.34\n44\n4h"
  sar = str.split("\n").map(s=> s.match(r).join("").replace(/[a-z]/,""));
console.log(sar);
```

Comment: Inconsistent results for `.1` and `.-1`, which give `.1` and `1` respectively.